# How to use kendo file upload with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am using kendo file upload with angularjs that i will be sending to the server  using Restfull Post request, below code i could not upload file using kendo AngularJs any help will be appreciated.

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
        <label for="issueNo" class="col-md-4">File name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input name="files"
               type="file"
               kendo-upload
               k-async="{ saveUrl: 'http://www.google.com', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: false }"
               k-select="onSelect"
             />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="addRiskForm.$invalid" ng-click="browse()">Browse</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
  $scope.$on('addDocument', function (s,id){
    $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey = id;
    $scope.viewDocumentWin.open().center();
  });

  $scope.onSelect = function(e) {
    var message = $.map(e.files, function(file) { return file.name; }).join(", ");
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: From the code it seems like you are trying to upload your file to Google instead of a RESTful api endpoint. Am I missing something, is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any WEB API class from your control.
your code :

```
k-async="{ saveUrl: 'http://www.google.com', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: false }"
```

should look something like:

```
k-async="{ saveUrl: '/upload/save', removeUrl: '/upload/remove', autoUpload: true }""
```